# Python setup.py egg_info failed wsgiref

Tags: python

I have a code for a twitch bot that connects to a database and collects data. I followed the tutorial on how to set this bot up and did every instruction. One of the last steps is to run command: pip install -r requirements.txt. Im correct folder and when I run in I get the error `SyntaxError: missing parentheses in call to 'print'` and dont know how to fix it. 
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxdz2.jpg)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says `SyntaxError: missing parentheses in call to 'print'`.

*Python2.7* does not use parentheses for the `print` statement, whereas *Python3* does.  Try running the program with *Python2.7* instead of *Python3*.